# Adaptive CSS for container div

Tags: iphone, html, css

I have a container div with 2 child panels to be implemented as adaptive layout.

By that, I simply mean that on desktop, the 2 child panels should float side-by-side
AND on iPhone, the 2 child panels should be one-below-another

Now below is my HTML;

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel1"></div>
<div class="panel2"></div>
</div>
```

For the CSS, i just use the media query for desktop/iPhone.

For desktop (i.e. higher available width), my CSS is

```
.panel1{width:50%;float:left} //Span 50% of desktop width
.panel2{width:50%;float:left} //Span 50% of desktop width
```

For iPhone (i.e. lower available width), my CSS is

```
.panel1{width:100%;float:left} //Span entire iPhone width
.panel2{width:100%;float:left} //Span entire iPhone width
```

Now my question is how should I code the container div such that it would work fine across all major browsers ?

i.e. Should I use "float" for the container in both the CSS (desktop/iPhone) OR do I play with the 2 child panels like making float:none ?

Actually I know giving the 2 child panels as

> width:100%;float:left

would work fine on iPhone ...But I am a bit uncomfortable with the though that they use float:left BUT appear on screen as one-below-other..

Please suggest some best practices for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kill the floats for the iPhone, you don't need those. Just use block-elements, they will go below eachother naturally, and use all available width automatically.

You can use `overflow: hidden` for the container div, so that it expands in height/width with the floats.

Comment: Thx a lot for that..I just tried what you said..if I use float:none for the 2 child panels and also add overflow:hidden for the container in iPhone CSS, the container is not expanding as per the child divs..

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into this?

Comment: With `float:none` there is no need for the `overflow:hidden` property on the container. But even with that property it should expand normally. And are you sure the iPhone is targeted with the media `handheld`? Modern phones render websites normally, you might want to use javascript to detect the browser and operating system.

Comment: Yes, it is not expanding as per the content.. Also for the media query, i am actually using screen width and not exactly device-width..so m wure there are no issues over there..

Comment: Not sure if ther can be some issues while toggling between properties in 2 separate css like overflow or float..though this looks less of a probability..